# LIB folder in ASP.NET MVC 6 project

Tags: asp.net, bower, azure-devops

Is the LIB folder under the **wwwroot** of an **asp.net mvc 6** app expected to be checked-into the source control like git or VS Team Services?

Is it expected to be created only on the developers machine through bower, and don't get from source control?

[image]

Exclude changes:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of the `lib` folder should be populated by `bower` via your `gulp` task. So you do not need to check-in/commit these files to source control, because they can be recreated by your "build" process.

Comment: Is there an option to ignore the LIB folder from checking into the TFS as well as the **sln** does not track the changes. I think I have experienced an issue of VS 2015 not responding well when more packages (npm, jspm, bower) are added. I assume the **nugget** package folders are not added to the solution by default but JavaScript packages do.